# How do you code for a dual action card in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

We are coding a new card game for a customer who would like cards to have "double actions" like the following:

> ***Deal +2 Damage to any Enemy Spaceship***
>
> OR
>
> ***Restore any of your Spaceships to Full Health***

Obviously we have Action 1 and Action 2 as separate parameters on the card itself, so that's not the problem.  If you think of card games like Hearthstone where you are dragging and dropping cards onto the game area.  How can the player inform the system which action they are playing?

Comment: Play some Sentinels of the Multiverse.

Comment: [Game Dev SE](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @TJWolschon - Didn't realize there was a Game Dev SE....learn something new every day.  Thank you.

Comment: This question is more on-topic there than it is here, as it's a little too broad for SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in multiple ways. Probably the easiest one is to have `List<YourBehaviour>`or `YourBehaviour[]` in the card class and to pass the index of the behaviour that the player chose in the constructor and set your main behaviour like so

```
Card(... int behaviourIndex)
{
   ...
   this.MainBehaviour = YourBehaviour[behaviourIndex];
}
```

Or have custom method in Card class like:

```
public void SetupMainBehaviour(int behaviourIndex)
{
   this.MainBehaviour = YourBehaviour[behaviourIndex];
}
```

When it comes to Unity you can have some cool popup and with multiple choices

Comment: Great idea.  So choose the card you want to play, then perhaps do a popup which has the text of each action from the card so the player can choose which one they want to use.  Then set it accordingly.